# Can't read j_username after failed login

Tags: jsp, servlets, websphere, servlet-filters

I use websphere jee form authentication, and I want to return the entered j_username in the error page.

I used a custom filter to intercept the call to j_security_check and added the j_username parameter to the request as an attribute, but when checking the attribute in the error page or in the controller I found it's always null. The parameter j_username was found in the filter before accessing j_security_check, the problem is after failed login attemp.

Why websphere when redirecting to the error url doesn't pass j_username and j_password, and how can I access j_username in the login error page?

Comment: Why? The user knows what he entered. Why do you need to tell him what he already knows?

Comment: First, that didn't answer the question. But, if you are curious, there are many reasons including you can't expect the customer to avoid typos and ask him to rememeber what he typed. Or you want to check if the login failure happened because the username doesn't exist at all in your DB and based on that show appropriate err message or redirect to signup page. There are many reasons but I'm more interested in an answer than a question:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I found that websphere 8.5 creates a session when the action is /j_security_check. So, I used a web filter for /j_security_check to store j_username parameter in that session, and when login failure happens, I retrieved the username from that session using ${sessionScope[STORED_USERNAME]}.

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

My guess is j_username is nulled out when a login failure occurs. You will probably have to retrieve the login name from the request in your filter and pass it on to the error page using request.getParameter("j_username") ?

Though I will say from a security perspective less information to the end user is better. I would not tell the end user that the username exists and  the password is bad because if someone is trying to hack the account then you've given them one piece of info they did not know which is "is the username valid"? I would display the username they entered but simply say "either the username does not exist or the password was invalid" and leave it ambiguous. This way the valid user will know if they typed their username incorrectly but the hacker doesn't know if he got it right or not.

Comment: The j_username is nulled when the server redirect to the error page. I agree about showing less information to the user for security reasons. But, this application is for internal use and not for public. But thanks for the info

Comment: Right. So you should be able to pull the user name using request.getParameter() before calling the login which then lets you save it to pass to the error page.